# CodeIgniter active record query only returning the first entry in the table

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Simple problem I'm stuck on:

Here is my active record query:

```
public function get_org()
  {
    return $this->db
          ->get('organizations')
          ->row();
  }
```

This only returns the first row in the DB.
If I get rid of `->row();` it returns this odd bit:

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#17 (8) {
  ["conn_id"]=>
  resource(8) of type (mysql link persistent)
  ["result_id"]=>
  resource(12) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }    
  ["custom_result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(2)
  ["row_data"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Whats odd is that the exact same query works perfectly elsewhere in my code for different tables.

Suggestions?

Comment: you have used row() function, so it return single row, use result_array() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like

```
public function get_org()
{
   $query = $this->db->get('organizations');

   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      $result_arr[] = $row;
   }
   return $result_arr; 
}
```

`row()` will return only one row of the result array.

Or you can also try with `result_array()` as **@Hashem Qolami** said like

```
public function get_org()
{
   $result = $this->db->get('organizations');
   return $result->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Good call. I still dont quite understand why it does it that way. I understand what `$row()` does, but it workes elsewhere. Meh.

Comment: Looking for `result_array()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the given code below:

```
$query = $this->db->get('organizations');
return $query->result_array();
```

To learn more about handling query results in CodeIgniter: [Handling query results in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)